# Different checksum value for '-' in sql server 2008 and 2016 so Can't compare modified data

Tags: sql-server

In 2008 the checksum value for '-' is 45 and in 2016 is 0 So when we calculating checksum for one value e.g 'AS' and 'AS-' the checksum for these 2 value is different in sql server 2008 and in 2016,the checksum value is same. I want the different value as like sql server 2008 for performing some operations

On sql 2008-

```
select checksum('AA')   --o/p- 2158
select checksum('AA-')  --o/p- 34509
```

on 2016-

```
select checksum('AA')   --o/p- 34472462
select checksum('AA-')  --o/p- 34472462
```

Answer (score 0):

> Checksum and binary_checksum are both affected by the locale and case
>   sensitivity settings of the server.  The varbinary is converted to a
>   string, then checksum is applied.  It is more likely your settings are
>   different between servers.

[MSDN - BINARY_CHECKSUM gives different results for same value](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/1041af36-7a40-4197-987a-0b924426c222/binarychecksum-gives-different-results-for-same-value?forum=transactsql)

I assume this is the case for CHECKSUM as well...
Perhaps something like this works correctly on both servers:

```
SELECT CHECKSUM('AA' COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS)
```

**Edit:
My answer is incorrect. It seems that my suggestion by including a COLLATE doesn't have the effect I expected. I will remove my answer shortly.**

Comment: BINARY_CHECKSUM() returns the same value if the elements of two expressions have the same type and byte representation. So, “2Volvo Director 20” and “3Volvo Director 30” will yield the same value, however the CHECKSUM() function evaluates the type as well as compares the two strings and if they are equal, then only the same value is returned... so as like I want in 2016

Comment: I understand. But as I imply, it might be the case that the CHECKSUM function is affected by locale and case sensitivity settings as well, just as BINARY_CHECKSUM(). To get the same results, it might be so that you need to "convert" your values to a specific collation, as I suggested. I am not able to test it quickly, however, since on my machine both my SQL servers (2014 and 2017) return the same result with your original query - probably because they also use the same server collation...

Comment: Never mind. My suggestion doesn't seem to work. Just tested it shortly on the same server with different values using accent sensitive/insensitive collations using COLLATE. Doesn't have the effects I assumed. Sorry...

Comment: @SSD I have been restless for three days now. I have thought about your comment repeatedly. You seem to be right, but I do not understand the logic behind it. I have upvoted the (currently still unanswered) question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41946650. I was hoping that you might able to provide an understandable answer to it.

Answer (score 0):

The differences are not related to the SQL Server Version, probably your 2016 server has a collation that includes Unicode characters

With varchar

```
select checksum('AA')   --o/p- 2158
select checksum('AA-')  --o/p- 34509
```

With nvarchar

```
select checksum(N'AA')   --o/p- 34472462
select checksum(N'AA-')  --o/p- 34472462
```

You can try casting as varchar

```
select checksum(CAST('AA' AS VARCHAR))   --o/p- 2158
select checksum(CAST('AA-' AS VARCHAR))  --o/p- 34509
```

If not, this collation worked for me

```
select checksum(CAST('AA' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_Pref_CP1_CI_AS as varchar))
```