# Better for checking duplicates in a table: clustered unique index or temp table with CHECKSUM?

Tags: sql-server

My table has 6 columns to which I insert rows of data. I want to skip duplicates. What is more efficient? Having a copy table, add CHECKSUM columns in both of them and check with TRIGGER on INSERT for duplicates. Or creating UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX on 3 columns with IGNORE_DUP_KEY = ON?

Comment: I'd say try to avoid triggers as much as possible

Comment: I'd try to avoid CHECKSUM too. Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41946650.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a safe and solid database design, going for an unique index or unique constraint would be the right way to go. As I see it, it is typically not necessary (and probably even less efficient) to use a separate table that gets filled with your own unique values by a trigger...

However, I would only use DUP_IGNORE_KEY temporarily when bulk inserting/migrating data and carefully check the resulting data afterwards. And even in that case, there are multiple ways to avoid it. In my 20 years as a software developer of database applications, I never had to use DUP_IGNORE_KEY. (Actually, I learned about it just now.) I would certainly *NEVER* use it permanently on an index in a production server. IMHO, it's about as ugly as old VB's "ON ERROR RESUME NEXT": you do not get an immediate reaction if something goes wrong!

Comment: So you wouldn't use any of my cases. What is the alternative? I need to check for duplicates on 3 columns.

Comment: I would use a unique index/constraint, but without DUP_IGNORE_KEY if it is a permanent solution on a production server.

Comment: Can you tell me why using DUP_IGNORE_KEY  is a bad idea?

Comment: When you specify it and you try to insert an already existing key in your table, the insert statement is simply ignored and has no effect. Any "changes" (or differences with any other data fields) seem to get lost. That's how I understand the behavior of DUP_IGNORE_KEY at least... IMHO, that's not nice. I personally would want to either insert a new record, update the existing record or simply do nothing at all. But if I execute a query, I would expect a change. Or an error. But it's a matter of preference. If you design your solution well, it might work correctly with DUP_IGNORE_KEY too.

Comment: If you really just want to skip duplicates and discard all inserted data in the case of a duplicate, using DUP_IGNORE_KEY might just be fine. It's just not the behavior I would normally expect from a database application.